# how to load a csv file into html using $.get()

Tags: jquery, html, csv

I'm unable to load data.csv file into my html using "$.get()" function.

```
My code:
==========
sample.html:
===========
<html> 
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="container"></div>
<script>

$.get('data.csv', function(data) {

// start the table
var html = '<table">';

// split into lines
var rows = data.split("\n");

// parse lines
rows.forEach( function getvalues(ourrow) {

// start a table row
html += "<tr>";

// split line into columns
var columns = ourrow.split(",");

html += "<td>" + columns[0] + "</td>";
html += "<td>" + columns[1] + "</td>";
html += "<td>" + columns[2] + "</td>";

// close row
html += "</tr>";
})
// close table
html += "</table>";

// insert into div
$('#container').append(html);

});
</script>

</body>

</html>

data.csv:
========
name,phone,nickname,state
bob,503,bobby,oregon
steve,707,stevie,california
```

I'm able to load the data of the csv file into a div.
But I don't want to load the data into a div. 
Can anyone please suggest me about loading a csv file into a html page .

Comment: `var html = '<table">';` - The extra double quote is causing it break.

Comment: Even though  i had corrected it to like this ,var html = "<table>"; I'm facing the same  problem.Actually I'm unable to load  the  data from the csv file into html

Comment: I had followed this link http://www.jqueryscript.net/table/jQuery-Plugin-To-Generate-A-Table-From-A-CSV-File-CSV-Parser.html

Comment: Besides @NickR's comment - your code seems to be fine. Hint: make sure you're running the code from a web server (and not, for example, locally using the file-system).

Comment: What further changes I need to do ,in order to load a csv file into a html page

Comment: Is it impossible to run from local file system ?

Comment: If you run it from `file://` then `<script src="//` won't work, as it needs to be on a web server for the double slash to work. (see protocol relative)

Comment: without using web server,can we load the data of the csv file using d3.js

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur suggestion